# My `js` file keep getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'albumCover' of undefined".

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'albumCover' of undefined" while I am trying to import data from 'album.js' to display all title, albumCover, etc.. inside my 'Album.js'.

This is my 'Album.js' where I am going to display all the 'album.js' information.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import albumData from './../data/albums';


class Album extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

const album = albumData.find( album => 
    {return album.slug === this.props.match.params.slug});

this.state = {
          album: album
};
}

render() {
    return (
      <section className="album">
        <img id="album-cover-art" src={this.state.album.albumCover} alt={this.state.album.title}/>
        <section id="album-info">
            <img id="album-cover-art" />
          <div className="album-details">
            <h1 id="album-title">{this.state.album.title}</h1>
            <h2 className="artist">{this.state.album.artist}</h2>
            <div id="release-info">{this.state.album.releaseInfo}</div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <table id="song-list">
       <colgroup>
         <col id="song-number-column" />
         <col id="song-title-column" />
         <col id="song-duration-column" />
       </colgroup>  
        <tbody>
        {this.state.album.songs.map( (song, index) =>
        <tr className="song" key={index} onClick={() => this.handleSongClick(song)} >
          <td className="song-actions">
            <button>
              <div className="ion-play"></div>
            </button>
          </td>
          <td className="song-title">{song.title}</td>
          <td className="song-duration">{song.duration}</td>
        </tr>
        )}
        </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
export default Album
```

This one is my 'album.js' where I store all the data of the album.

```
// this album data are being stored
export default [{
title: 'The Colors',
artist: 'Pablo Picasso',
releaseInfo: '1909 Spanish Records',
albumCover: '/assets/images/album_covers/04.gif',
slug: 'the-colors',
songs: [
    { title: 'Blue', duration: '2:41', audioSrc: '/assets/music/blue.mp3' },
    { title: 'Green', duration: '1:43', audioSrc: '/assets/music/green.mp3' },
    { title: 'Red', duration: '4:28', audioSrc: '/assets/music/red.mp3' },
    { title: 'Pink', duration: '2:33', audioSrc: '/assets/music/pink.mp3' },
    { title: 'Magenta', duration: '6:14', audioSrc: '/assets/music/magenta.mp3' }
]
}, {
  title: 'The Telephone',
  artist: 'Guglielmo Marconi',
  releaseInfo: '1909 EM',
  albumCover: '/assets/images/album_covers/02.jpg',
  slug: 'the-telephone',
  songs: [
    { title: 'Blue', duration: '2:41', audioSrc: '/assets/music/blue.mp3' },
    { title: 'Green', duration: '1:43', audioSrc: '/assets/music/green.mp3' },
    { title: 'Red', duration: '4:28', audioSrc: '/assets/music/red.mp3' },
    { title: 'Pink', duration: '2:33', audioSrc: '/assets/music/pink.mp3' },
    { title: 'Magenta', duration: '6:14', audioSrc: '/assets/music/magenta.mp3' }
  ]
}];
```

Comment: Your `find` seems to be unsuccessful

Comment: And you're sure that `const album = albumData.find...` worked?

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using **react-router-dom**. I `console.log(album)`, and it prints out objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well when you pass matched `slug` but when there is no match `slug` it raises an error, you should handle error for unmatched values.

check here:
https://react-stack-post-sample-10.stackblitz.io

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your response! Do you have a link where I can read more information how to handle `slug`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Your welcome. `slug` is the name used in your object structure. It's not any special subject.